# Semantic difference between "com" and "na"

Tags: gramática

I found two examples:

> Deu de cara com a parede

and

> Deu de cara na parede ?

And was wondering if the literal difference is the same as in English i.e. hit your head **with** the wall v hit your head **in** the wall

And whether one is more natural to use than the other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**dar de cara na parede**, *ran into the wall as in collide with*. Physically.

***dar de cara com*** is *not run into in the sense of collide with*. It means to encounter, to come across. to unexpectedly see. **To come face to face with someone or something.**

Comment: Thank you! I was not 100% sure because I saw somewhere that "dar de cara com" was more appropriate for referring to people/humans and supposedly awkward when referring to objects

Comment: Lambie I do think «Dar de cara com a parede» can mean to hit yout head on the wall, but I believe it is figurative or something like that, for it also work with «topar com a parede». You stand correct, though.

Comment: @Schilive Sai correndo do prédio e dei de cara com a parede. Não tenho certeza que queira dizer a minha cara bateu contra a parede.